# Using sed to set PermitRootLogin on OSX

Tags: regex, macos, bash, sed

I'm trying to figure out how to enable `PermitRootLogin` with OSX `sed`.

I know about the OSX `sed` issue where you have to give an empty string at the start.

I just need the regex I actually need to do:

if `#PermitRootLogin` yes or `#PermitRootLogin` no then replace with `PermitRootLogin yes`

I've got:

```
sudo sed -i '' 's/#PermitRootLogin no/PermitRootLogin yes/g' /etc/sshd_config
```

But this doesn't include if `##PermitRootLogin yes`

Comment: doubled string replace indicator `s/s/`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The version of `sed` in OS X requires a parameter after `-i` for the backup file suffix.

If you don't want a backup file, you have to provide an explicit empty string:

```
sed -i '' 's/^#?PermitRootLogin \(no\|yes\)/PermitRootLogin yes/' /etc/sshd_config
```

Without this argument, it's taking the `s/.../.../` command as the suffix, and `/etc/sshd_config` as sed editing command.

Note that some time between Snow Leopard and El Capitan, the location of this SSH configuration file moved from `/etc/sshd_config` to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Comment: Ok, this is making the sed work properly, but the regex isn't working still...

Comment: There was an extra `s/` at the beginning of the command. Also, `|` needs to be esaped in `sed` to form alternatives.

Comment: seems to be `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, at least on 10.12

Comment: @CharlieGorichanaz In El Capitan as well. I've updated the answer to note this.